# No Persistence provider for EntityManager X in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have an ejb class that uses an EntityManager:

```
@Remote
public interface TestEjbInt {
    public List<Test> getAllTest();
}

@Stateful
public class TestEjb implements TestEjbInt{
   private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "Test"; 
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test")
   private EntityManager managerTest;
   //EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
   //EntityManager managerTest = emf.createEntityManager();

    public List<Test> getAllTests() {

        List<Test> tests = managerTest.createQuery(
            "select * " +
            "from Test")
        .getResultList();
        return tests;
    }
}
```

Tried different things, added in Application.java:
@SpringBootApplication

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    /*@Bean
    public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }*/

    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
         LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("test");
        return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

When running the server I get an error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in
>   ema.Test: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager named test

I mention that I am using spring boot and I don't have the persistece.xml, I configured via application.properties.

Comment: `I mention that I am using spring boot and I don't have the persistece.xml`: but you're telling the EJB container to inject an EntityManager. Where should the container get the EntityManager to be injected if you don't have `persistence.xml`? And I am wondering why you need the EJB if you're using Spring and vice versa.

Comment: Remove the `unit name` Spring boot will create the default one unless you explicitly define the name. So remove it and remove your explicitly added `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` configuration method.

Comment: Avoid mixing up EJB with Spring. Ensure you have hibernate-core dependency in your project too.